# Can the Icon be disposed safely after a call to Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, idisposable

for a user control that shows, among other things, file paths and the associated file icon for a set of given files we extract the `Icon` of those files and create `ImageSource` instances for later use.

Roughly:

```
FileIcons aIcon = new FileIcons(filePath);
System.Drawing.Icon i = aIcon.GetSmallIconWithTypeName(isFolder, out typeName);
ImageSource imgSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(i.Handle, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
```

Irrelevant but just for info: The FileIcons class uses SHGetFileInfo and ExtractIconEx of the Shell32.dll to get the Icon.

The interesting part is after the call to `Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(...)`:

Can I safely `.Dispose()` the `Icon` the `ImageSource` was created from AND keep using the `ImageSource` afterwards?

Thanks for the help,

Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, there is no link between the bitmap and the icon, the former being an independent in-memory image derived from, but not linked to the latter.

Don't forget to p/invoke `DestroyIcon()` for `i` as well.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I would have forgotten DestroyIcon() thanks for the reminder!

Comment: When calling DestroyIcon the icons will disappear when they are still in use somewhere.

To avoid that you must call Freeze and use the copy instead.